# List field with 'Select All' option?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I have a Product content type with a list field of Groups (another content type). I would like to be able to have a 'Select All' item in the Groups list that allows the user to relate the product to all groups.

Note: This isn't the same as using javascript or ctrl+a to select all items in the list, because that approach would mean that when a new group is added it would not automatically be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two workarounds that hit my mind, depending on the logic your UI could have.
1. If having no Group assigned could mean "assigned to all" - go for it.
2. Else: consider adding additional checkbox (boolean) field labeled "Fits all" (or whatever you like).

Comment: Thanks Artur, I'm thinking of going with the first approach. If there are no other suggestions I will mark yours as the answer.